# Order by query producing wrong result

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQL and I am attempting to create a database relating to Formula 1 as a bit of practise.

What I would like to do is create a trigger so that when I update the Drivers’ points the trigger will set off a code that will add the points of the two drivers, who drive for the seam team, together and place the result into the Constructor_Points column on the Constructor table for the team in which the two drivers race for. For example, when the Red Bull drivers finish first and second I want the total number of points gained (43 in this case) to be added to Red Bull’s total points in the Constructor Table when the points has been added on the F1 Drivers table.

The issue I am asking for help on relates to a query I am submitting (see below) which isn't giving me the response that I had wished for

here is the `query`:

```
select Team, sum (Points) as "Total_Points", min ("Highest_race_finish") as "Highest Race 
Finish", max (Total_top_Position) as 'Total Top Position'
from "F1 Drivers"
group by Team
order by Total_Points desc, Highest_race_finish asc, 'Total_top_Position' asc;
```

The table however produces the wrong result. Here is the incorrect part of the table

Team, Total_Points, Highest Race Finish, Total Top Position - these are the columns

```
Marussia, 0, 13, 1
Caterham  0, 14, 1
Williams  0, 11, 1
```

What the table should do is place Williams above Marussua and Caterham because the Highest race Position for Williams is lower (numerically) than it is for Marussia and Caterham. However, the table has positioned the other teams correctly when they happen to be joint on points, such as Lotus and Ferrari and McLaren and Sauber

Team, Total_Points, Highest Race Finish, Total Top Position - these are the columns

```
Lotus,  40, 1, 1
Ferrari 40, 2, 1                                   
Sauber,  4, 8, 1
McLaren  4, 9, 1
```

Why is this error occurring? If you need any more info, please ask.

Hopefully this all makes sense. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should not have spaces in your table / column names… Very bad practice.

Comment: How stupid of me. Yeah. That's fixed it. Thanks for your help. I have removed the spaces from the column names in the code and the result is correct.

Comment: Actually, he doesn't. He has '_' instead. He does have spaces in the resultset names, but that's OK. (Neither my nor Fabien's positions are accepted 100%!)

Comment: from "F1 Drivers" => that's the table name. It's very unconventional to have spaces in tables, columns, indexes, aliases, etc. I did not even know you could do that.

Comment: What data types does those columns have?

Comment: Simon, that is what I thought, but I added '_' into the resultset names and the query produces the correct result.

Comment: All columns are integer apart from Team which is text.

Comment: Aside from the meaningless argument about whether your table should have spaces (it shouldn't, but it isn't even remotely related to what's causing your problem), please pick a platform. This is tagged both `mysql` and `sql-server`, which [probably isn't appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system).

Comment: I'm using SQLite Maestro, perhaps something I should have stated.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `order by` clause:

```
order by Total_Points desc, Highest_race_finish asc, 'Total_top_Position' asc;
```

The third part is a constant string.  The string is `'Total_top_Position'`.  Ordering by a constant is a no-op.  It doesn't do anything useful.

You probably mean:

```
order by Total_Points desc, Highest_race_finish asc, Total_top_Position asc;
```

When writing SQL, only using single quotes for string constants and date constants.  They shouldn't be used for any other purpose.

Comment: The issue has been solved, it was my fault for not specifying SQlite. I added '_' in the resultset names and the order is correct.